# Dask Array from DataFrame

Tags: dask

Is there a way to easily convert a DataFrame of numeric values into an Array? Similar to `values` with a pandas DataFrame. I can't seem to find any way to do this with the provided API, but I'd assume it's a common operation.

Comment: https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/generated/dask.dataframe.DataFrame.to_dask_array.html

Answer (score 9, accepted):

#### Edit: yes, now this is trivial

You can use the `.values` property

```
x = df.values
```

#### Older, now incorrect answer

At the moment there is no trivial way to do this.  This is because dask.array needs to know the length of all of its chunks and dask.dataframe doesn't know this length.  This can not be a completely lazy operation.

That being said, you can accomplish it using [dask.delayed](http://dask.pydata.org/en/latest/delayed-overview.html) as follows:

```
import dask.array as da
from dask import compute

def to_dask_array(df):
    partitions = df.to_delayed()
    shapes = [part.values.shape for part in partitions]
    dtype = partitions[0].dtype

    results = compute(dtype, *shapes)  # trigger computation to find shape
    dtype, shapes = results[0], results[1:]

    chunks = [da.from_delayed(part.values, shape, dtype) 
              for part, shape in zip(partitions, shapes)]
    return da.concatenate(chunks, axis=0)
```

Comment: This makes sense, thanks for the response. I figured using `to_delayed` would be one way to do this, thanks for posting a method that can do this.

Answer (score 3):

Dask now has a `DataFrame.to_dask_array()` function to do this.

Docs: https://docs.dask.org/en/stable/generated/dask.dataframe.DataFrame.to_dask_array.html#dask.dataframe.DataFrame.to_dask_array

Answer (score 2):

I think, there might be another way shorter.

```
import dask.array as da
import dask.dataframe as df

ruta ='...'
df = dd.read_csv(...)
x = df_reg['column you want to transform in array']

def transf(x):
    xd=x.to_delayed()
    full = [da.from_delayed(i, i.compute().shape, i.compute().dtype) for i in xd]
    return da.concatenate(full)

x_array=transf(x)
```

In addition, if you want to convert a DaskDataframe with N columns, and therefore, each array element will be another array like this:

array((x,x2,x3),(y1,y2,y3),....)

You have to change the order:

from:

```
i.compute().dtype
```

to

```
i.compute().dtypes
```

Thanks